# iOS Apple Watch: I was able to submit an app with an id that doesn't exist. Is this normal?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, apple-developer

I was recently able to submit an App with an id that doesn't exist on the apple developer website. I am not sure this is normal or not. This is the apple identifier I am using in Xcode for Apple watch extension.

```
com.myApp.watchkitapp.wkextension
```

However, this id doesn't exist on the apple developer website. I just clicked on "automatically manage to sign" checkbox and allowed me to submit the App. Not sure if this is normal or why this works.

I was always under the impression the app id has to exist.

Edit: Xcode never created an App Id as well.

Edit 2: I do have the app id `com.myApp.wkextension`, but not `com.myApp.watchkitapp.wkextension` in apple developer portal. Does xcode somehow corrects this?

Comment: Xcode will create one for you, did you check the developer portal app id's section?

Comment: Xcode never created it at all. That what's also strange.

Comment: Did you check the developers portal? If the app is uploaded to Itunes connect, it probably generated one for you. Where are you looking to check the id?

Comment: This is where I am checking it https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

Comment: I've updated my post with more information that might help.